# Can I restore overlaid scenes?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a beginner developer using Unity. I stupidly named my project scene SampleScene and was working on it. I wanted a cool effect, so I downloaded an effect asset from the asset store.

I downloaded an asset and its SampleScene overlayed the SampleScene I was working on. Can it be repaired? Is this irreversible forever?

Comment: hm in general start using version control (git, plastic, etc) ... if you are lucky i might be in the system trash - otherwise maybe try https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/recover-overwritten-files.html and similar searches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless you made a backup of the project before you imported the new SampleScene. The amount of people I've seen this happen to makes you think Unity should fix this issue. Anyways, sorry this happened to you and best of luck.